# Find out if HTML code represents visible text/image

Tags: java, html, regex

I have a string which contains some HTML code. I would like to find out if the HTML code represents visible text or an image. I used Java to solve this problem using the following regular expressions (I know you cannot parse HTML using RegExps, but I thought for what I am up to RegExps are enough).

```
public static String regex_html_tags_1 = "<\\s*br\\s*[/]?>";
public static String regex_html_tags_2 = "<\\s*([a-zA-Z0-9]+)\\s*([^=/>]+\\s*=\\s*[^/>]+\\s*)*\\s*/>"; 
public static String regex_html_tags_3 = "<\\s*([a-zA-Z0-9]+)\\s*([^=>]+\\s*=\\s*[^>]+\\s*)*\\s*>\\s*</\\s*\\1\\s*>"; 

public static String[] HTMLWhiteSpaces = {"&nbsp;", "&#160;"};
```

The code using these RegExps works fine for strings like

```
<h2></h2>
```

or alike. But a string

```
<img src="someImage.png"></img>
```

is also thought of as being empty.

Does anyone have a better idea than using RegExps to find out if some HTML code actually represents human readable text when it is interpreted by a browser? Or do you think my approach eventually leads to success?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Do you count `display: hidden` as invisible?

Comment: Who would make a page that's NOT human-readable? I don't get it.

Comment: The HTML that I am talking about is not a (web) page. The content is part of an XML file that describes a property of "something". And if this description is not human readable, the property shall not appear in a document that shows the property of the "something".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using [JSoup](http://jsoup.org/). It let's you parse HTML documents using css selectors (jquery-style).

A very simple example to select all non-empty elements would be:

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://my.awesome.site.com").get();
Elements nonEmpties = doc.select(":not(:empty)");
```

The *full-blown* solution will of course require some extra work to do, like

- iterating over lists of elements,
- checking css styles (for `display` or `visibility` or sizes or overlaying elements)
- checking `src` attributes for images
- etc

but it's definitely worth it. You'll learn a new framework, discover possibilities to 'hide' content in HTML / CSS and - most important - stop using regular expressions for HTML parsing ;-)

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to JSoup. The library looks very promising. But when I try your code, I get the following exception

    Exception in thread "main" org.jsoup.select.Selector$SelectorParseException: Could not parse query ':empty': unexpected token at ':empty'

Comment: Well, to be honest, I did not test if that works, and unfortunately, [it seems, JSoup does not support `:empty:` pseudo-selector](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/select/Selector.html).

Answer (score 1):

I came up with the following code, which works fine in my setting in which I do not have to consider invisible elements.

```
// HTML white spaces that might occur in between tags; this list probably needs to be extended
public static String[] HTML_WHITE_SPACES = {"&nbsp;", "&#160;"};

/**
 * check if the given HTML text contains visible text or images
 * 
 * @param htmlText String the text that is checked for visibility
 * @return boolean    (1) true if the htmlText contains some visible elements 
 *                 or (2) false in case (1) does not hold
 */
public static boolean containsVisibleElements(String htmlText) {

    // do not analyze the HTML text if it is blank already
    if (StringUtil.isBlank(htmlText)) {
        return false;
    }

    // the string from which all whitespaces are removed
    String htmlTextRemovedWhiteSpaces = htmlText; 

    // first, remove white spaces from the string
    for (String whiteSpace: HTML_WHITE_SPACES) {
        htmlTextRemovedWhiteSpaces = htmlTextRemovedWhiteSpaces.replaceAll(whiteSpace, "");
    }

    // the HTML text is blank 
    if (StringUtil.isBlank(htmlTextRemovedWhiteSpaces)) {
        return false;
    }

    // parse the HTML text from which the white space have been removed
    Document doc = Jsoup.parse(htmlTextRemovedWhiteSpaces);

    // find real text within the body (and its children)
    String text = doc.body().text(); 

    // there exists visible text
    if (!StringUtil.isBlank(text.trim())) {
        return true;
    }

    // now we know that there does not exist visible text and that the string 
    // htmlTextRemovedWhiteSpaces is not blank

    // look for images as they are visible and not a text ;-)
    Elements images = doc.select("img");

    // there do not exist any image elements
    if (images.isEmpty()) {
        return false;
    }       

    // none of the above checks succeeded, so there must exist some visible elements such as text or images
    return true;
}
```